# Error when installing libpgm package in anaconda on windows

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm a new programmer with python. I want to use libpgm for my project. I installed Anaconda for Python 2.7 on my 64 bit Windows 7.
when i type `import libpgm`i get `ImportError: No module named libpgm`
I don't know how install it on my windows.
Is there every one who can help me?
Thanks...

Comment: Something like `conda install pip` if you don't already have `pip` then `pip install libpgm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Anaconda installation folder you have a folder called "Scripts". Inside this folder pip.exe is located. Navigate to this folder in your commandline and then execute:

> pip.exe install libpgm

from your command line.